# ambient air temp. sensor reading -40 on 2004 Jeep Grand Cherokee Laredo

Tags: jeep

The old sensor got broken during a accident with a deer. I've replaced the sensor and it's reading -40 deg. Is there a reset on this unit? The sensor worked about a year after the wreck until the plastic end finally broke off. What's the secret to getting it to read at all?? Is it in the computer chip or do I have a wire that is shorted out?? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you give the engine size, and 2 vs 4 wheel I can provide more detailed troubleshooting to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The wire going to the sensor is not connected (most likely) or is grounded out somewhere. It's also possible that the switch is bad, but you said you have replaced it.

-40 is the lower limit, it will read -40 when it's unplugged or grounded depending on how it's set up, most are set up for the former.

Comment: Thanks Larry. My neighbor has three Jeeps and after talking with him he agrees with you. So I'll have to find a new harness and install it. I appreciate your info. Oh the engine is a 4.0 six cylinder and it's a 4WD. Just saw the second part of your note.